# How to use mscorlib.dll instead of mscorlib.ni.dll?

Tags: c#, .net, dll, jit, newrelic

I'm trying to connect my app to use APM (New Relic), but Non-IIS App is preventing me from connecting my app to `new relic`.
When my app is `running` using "process explorer" and I notice `mscorlib.ni.dll`.

From this article:
https://discuss.newrelic.com/t/relic-solution-net-framework-agent-installation-issues-a-troubleshooting-guide/55166

I'm stuck at this part

> mscorlib.dll is missing - mscorlib.dll is required to be present. It’s
>   presence is how the .NET Framework agent identifies your application
>   as a .NET app. If it is missing, please double-check to make sure your
>   application meets the compatibility requirements 5 for monitoring by
>   the .NET Framework agent. If you don’t see mscorlib.dll, but you do
>   see mscorlib.ni.dll, then check to see if you’re using a native image
>   module (such as NGEN). The .NET agent can not monitor applications
>   that use a native image mscorlib.ni.dll assembly.

my app using `mscorlib.ni.dll` instead of `mscorlib.dll`, can someone guide me how to use mscorlib.dll ?

Comment: Hmm, no, there is no practical way to have a .NET program loading only mscorlib.ni.dll but not mscorlib.dll.  There were some very wonky linker tools in the early days of .NET that might have messed with that.  But today you'll have to mistrust what you see, make sure the tool you use is capable of listing both managed and unmanaged DLLs.  Try it first on a console mode app that has a Console.ReadLine() statement in Main().

Comment: @HansPassant I create a simple console app just print and inspect the process explorer is already included mscorlib.ni.dll, I also try to create .net framework 2.0 app ends up the same. I just wonder how are others peoples using new relic to monitor the metrics of the apps? since for the web app is using mscorlib.dll and non-iis app is using mscorlib.ni.dll. Can you explain some more