# why the module of an assembly cannot be found?

Tags: c#, .net, clr, .net-assembly

I made a custom library (test.dll) and created a console application that references my library. of course I added the reference in VS. so the code is sth like:

```
//use the type in test.dll
Car c = new Car(); //Car is defined in test.cs which compiled into test.dll
c.SpeedUp();
string pID = Console.ReadLine();
int theProcID = int.Parse(pID);
theProc = Process.GetProcessById(theProcID);
ProcessModuleCollection theMods = theProc.Modules;
foreach (ProcessModule pm in theMods)
{
   string info = $"-> Mod Name: {pm.ModuleName}";
   Console.WriteLine(info);
}
```

so I found the process id of the console application via task manager, then I type the id in, but I couldn't find the 'test.dll' in the list, I can see a lot of other dlls such as 'mscore.dll','mscorlib.ni.dll', 'user32.dll etc', so what did I go wrong?

by the way, what's the difference between 'mscorlib.ni.dll' and famous 'mscorlib.dll'?

Comment: Is the code using the library? They aren't loaded into memory until they're used

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen. Yes I used the library for sure, even creates a couple of instances of class defined in the test.dll.

Comment: Could you add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Regarding the mscorlib.ni.dll: try not to ask multiple questions combined. You can already find the answer on StackOverflow, for instance [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51873893/how-to-use-mscorlib-dll-instead-of-mscorlib-ni-dll)

Comment: im not seeing anything clear that would have come from your test.dll

Comment: @BugFinder I added some additional code, please check

Comment: Depends what speedup does.  If its say takes a value and adds a number, and never uses it itcan be thrown away by the compiler.  Please produce a [mcve] for this

Answer (score 0):

I try it with netcore, and I can see the referenced test.dll